# Alpakka S3 download file from bucket, save to file, and have filename available for next part in flow

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, akka-stream, alpakka

I am trying to build code that consumes S3 keys then download those files from S3, then saves that data to a file on disk with the keyname (required for a process further along the flow) and as an output returns the key/filename. What I have till so far is;

```
    val x: Sink[String, Future[IOResult]] =
      Flow[String].flatMapConcat(key => S3.download("somebucket", key)).
        withAttributes(S3Attributes.settings(useVersion1Api)).
        collect{ case Some(x) => x._1 }.
        flatMapConcat(identity).toMat(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get("???????")))(Keep.right)
```

What I currently have downloads the file, but does not;
- use the key name as filename
- returns the filename ( it should not be a sink but a flow )

I would appreciate any pointers. I just started with alpakka and akka streams. Likely I need somehow to pass the key within a tuple ,but I can't seem to figure out how to later use that part of the tuple.

Using cchantep first suggestion likely settling on;

```
    val s3FileSaveFlow: Flow[String, (String, ObjectMetadata), NotUsed] =
      Flow[String].flatMapConcat(key => S3.download("somebucket", key) collect{ case Some(src) => key -> src}).
        flatMapConcat{ case (key,(src,meta)) => {
          src.to(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(key)))
          Source.single((key,meta))
        }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val x: Sink[String, Future[IOResult]] =
  Flow[String].flatMapConcat(key => 
    S3.download("somebucket", key).collect {
      case Some(src) => key -> SRC
    })
```

Then you have the `key` and byte `src`.

If you want to have a look at [Benji S3 DSL](https://zengularity.github.io/benji/s3/usage.html) (I'm contributor of):

```scala
import akka.stream.scaladsl.FileIO

Flow[String].flatMapConcat { objKey =>
  s3.bucket("somebucket").obj(objKey).get().
    viaMat(FileIO.toPath(Path.get("/basedir", objKey)))(Keep.right)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and suggestions, I have edited my answer to reflect the change of the code based on your first suggestion.  Since you have experience, would a Source.single within the flatMapConcat be a correct use?

Comment: `{
          src.to(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(key)))
          Source.single((key,meta))
        }` is side-effecting, not recommended

Comment: What would be a correct way to return (key,meta) so that the entire thing is a flow? Checking https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/25242/commits/1de7dadeffdefcf91653f1aa1e833e9f9c15eb8b seems to suggest to me that there is an optimization for returning source.single inside flatmapconcat . Your thoughts?